# send and recieve data from html and express using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api

I have two pages admin.hbs and gallery.hbs. I need to render the gallery page on clicking a button on the admin page. I need to send the ID of the div the button was present in admin page to express using javascript .Using that ID I try to make a call to the api endpoint and then ,I try to render the gallery page based on the response from the api endpoint in express.

Is there any other alternative to send data from html to express?

How do I send data from html to express and then render a page based on the data received from express - instead of populating a div?

I basically need to get the id of the div the button was present in the admin page. Send that ID to the server (express) , server uses that id to make an call to an api endpoint and receives data , and that data is passed as params to render gallery page using hbs

Please find my code below :

```
<!--Div of Admin page whose ID is to be sent to express -->
<div class="card-container wrapper">    
   <div class="row">
      {{#each albums}}
         <div class="col-md-4 mt-6 albums" id="{{this.id}}">
           <div class="card">  
              <img class="card-img-top" src="{{this.imagelink}}" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body text-center">
              <h4 class="card-title">{{this.albumtitle}}</h4>
              <p class="card-text span3">{{this.description}}</p>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark buttons">Add Pictures</button>
            </div>                           
           </div>
         </div>
       {{/each}}
   </div>
 </div>
```

On clicking the button "Add pictures" I need to send the id of that particular div to express- its done using a ajax call.

```
   <script>       
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('buttons');  
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {    
         console.log($(this).closest('div').parent().parent().attr("id"));   
         var url = "";
         let url="http://localhost:3000/create/"+$(this).closest('div').parent().parent().attr("id");
         fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
            .then( (result) => {
             console.log('success:', result)
                    })
            .catch(error => console.log('error:', error));    
        });}
    </script>
```

Express code :

```
app.get('/create/:id', (req, res) => {

request({
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Client-ID ' + 'xxxxx'},
    url:`https://api.imgur.com/3/account/xxxx/album/${id}`,
  },(error,response,body)=>{
     if(!error && response.statusCode=== 200){
           //console.log(JSON.parse(body));
           var images=JSON.parse(body).data.images;
           for(var i =0;i<images.length;i++){
           console.log(images[i].link);
           array.push({ imagelink : images[i].link});

          }
          //Render another page(gallery) based on the response from the api endpoint
          res.render('gallery' ,{title :result.albumtitle, description : result.decription, album:array})

        }else{
            console.log('Unable to fetch album info');
        }
    });
```

I am being able to get the id from html but how do I render a page as response in express ,because , now the result is being passed to the fetch call as plain text instead of rendering a page in html ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works, in the sense that `result` *is* the rendered HTML page. You are making an ajax call, and the response to this ajax call is a full HTML page, in the form of a text. But then it just stays there, in memory, without doing anything. You can console.log it and all. But what you want is to render it in the view .

For this, you can fill a div with the received HTML, so the content of this div is dynamic : `$("someDiv").html(result)`

Comment: My problem is , I need a new page to be rendered and not a div

Answer (score 0):

The response going back to **fetch** call made from HTML is the natural behavior of the AJAX call.

I understand that you are trying to render **gallery** page from your current page. I would recommend you to do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" onclick="location.href='http://localhost:3000/create/'+{{this.id}}" class="btn btn-dark buttons">Add Pictures</button>
```

This way the button click redirects the user to create page which renders the desired content. I hope this helps.